# Python set/tuple operations iteration

Tags: python

I have a `set` of `tuple(a, b, c)`. How can I return a list of all `a` inside this `set`? Is there something like `.keys()` as dictionaries have?

Comment: `[t[0] for t in myset]` will probably work.

Comment: On another note how do i search for a tuple that contains a certain t[0] in this set?

Comment: @goodcow `[t for t in my_set if t[0] == your_desired_value]` would work for that.

Comment: [t for t in mySet if t[0] == value] gives you a list of tuples where t[0] is what you're looking for

Comment: I think `[t for t in my_set if t[0] == your_value]` can suit better.

Comment: Wow such consensus, thanks guys

Comment: And actually I think, in order to get a tuple or `None` if it doesn't exist, that you can use: `next((t for t in my_set if t[0] == your_value), None)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myList = [tup[0] for tup in mySet]`

They're not "keys" per se.

Comment: Glad to see a nice consensus on SO :P

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
data = set([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
all_a = [a for a, b, c in data]
```

Or if the tuples can be of varying length:

```
all_a = [t[0] for t in data]
```